# Remove double quotes from asset_path output

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, assets

I am using `asset_path` in a selector to add multiple background images to it.

On the SCSS, this is my code:

```
background-image: url(asset-path('bg1.jpg')), url(asset-path('bg2.jpg')), url(asset-path('bg3.jpg'))
```

And this is the output in the CSS

```
background-image: url("somehashbg1.jpg"), url("somehashbg2.jpg"), url("somehashbg3.jpg")
```

CSS is not rendering it. It is not expecting quotes inside the `url(...)` for multiple backgrounds

Is there a way to strip quotes out of the output of asset-path?

Comment: The problem is not what you think it is.  Double quotes around the path is perfectly valid CSS.  Are you sure the problem isn't that the images aren't in the correct location?

Comment: when I remove the quotes they seem to work. with quotes and multiple background the chrome's inspector don't show the second and the third images

Answer (score 0):

`asset-url` without the `url()` is the way to go

`background-image: asset-url(bg1.jpg'), asset-url('bg2.jpg'), asset-url('bg3.jpg')`